# How to get a url value into a form field when the link is clicked in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

I want to create a ref link like this in laravel 5.4[Registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwpl6.jpg)
 emails example.com
For every registered user and when the link is click it should redirect to the registration form where the ref value is automatically get into the REF form field as given in the image. Here are the related images [RegistrationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFLP.png)

Comment: You want to create ref link or you want to add to form!! What have you tried so far, show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Updated the link generation based on comments

Generate the referral link using the logged in user's email. Assuming you have the logged in user as `$user`, if not replace it with `auth()->user()->email`. Note that this will need logged in user's email. So it goes without saying that you need to be logged in before to generate the ref link.

If you pass the currently logged in user to your view from controller then do this, where `$user = auth()->user();`

```
<a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => $user->email]) }}" target="_blank">Referral register link</a>
```

If you want to directly access the logged in user's email

```
<a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => auth()->user()->email]) }}" target="_blank">Referral register link</a>
```

This is how it would look like in the view.

```
<a href="http://example.com/register?ref=example@example.com" target="_blank">Referral register link</a>
```

Add the following code in your registration form depending on how you create the form.

```
<input type="text" name="referrer" value="{{ request('ref') }}">

Or

{!! Form::text('referrer', request('ref')) !!}
```

Comment: This could have fully solve the problem but the error is if I 
<a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => $user->email]) }}" target="_blank">Referral register link </a> it generate undefined user and if use  <a>  href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => auth()->user()->email]) }}">Register</a>

Comment: This could have fully solve the problem but the error is if I 
<a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => $user->email]) }}" target="_blank">Referral register link </a> it generate undefined user and if use  <a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => auth()->user()->email]) }}">Register</a> it gives "Trying to get property of non-object error"

Comment: And moreover how would the url link like http://example.com/register?ref=refemail@gmail.com be generated from <a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => $user->email]) }}" target="_blank">Referral register link</a> when clicked

Comment: @Odayo I've updated the answer. You should at least know some basics to resolve issues like this. I've clearly mentioned in my answer that $user is the logged in user object passed to the view. I've added another way to directly. You need to make user a user is logged in to be able to generate ref links for them. If a user is not logged in then `auth()->user()` would return null and you can't fetch the email.

Comment: Yes @sonesis I've done this <a href="http://example.com/register?ref=example@example.com" target="_blank">Referral register link</a> even before posting the question but I could not fashion out a convectional way of wrapping the link like this<a href="http://example.com/register?ref=$user->email" target="_blank">Referral register link</a> into the link navigation. I did some stuff to the RegistrationController but no result. And moreso you know user aren't login nor registered yet so I think thats why <a href="http://example.com/register?ref={{ Auth::User()->email}}" ></a> is not working

Answer (score 0):

**The idea like this:** In the email make a link like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => auth()->user()->email]) }}">Register</a>
```

In your form, you can add hidden or disabled textbox like this:

```
<input type="textbox" name="ref" value="{{ request()->get('ref') }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add it to the session object in your controller like this:

```
function create(Request $request) {
    return view('register')->with(['ref' => $request->query('ref')]);
}
```

And populate your form with `{!! Former::populate(['ref' => $ref]) !!}` if you're using [Former](https://github.com/formers/former) or use form model binding (see [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-form-model-binding))

Example form markup in **register.blade.php** with Former:

```
{!!Former::horizontal_open()
        ->method('POST') !!}
    {!! Former::populate(['ref' => $ref]) !!}
    {!! Former::text('ref') !!}
    ...
    {!! Former::actions()
        ->large_primary_submit('Create') # Combine Bootstrap directives like "lg and btn-primary"
        ->large_inverse_reset('Reset') !!}
{!!Former::close() !!}
```